# How do I transpose rows into columns?

Tags: t-sql, pivot, transpose

probably a simple one, is there a way to quickly transpose my data so that it reads across instead of by row.

[image]

Above is the current output but would like it to read across eg

```
AttendanceNumber, ExamDate, ExamCode1, ExamCode2, ExamCode3, .......ExamCode20
```

my sql is

```
SELECT  [AttendanceNumber]
       ,[ExaminationDate]
       ,[ExamExaminationCode]
  FROM [Radiotherapy].[dbo].[tblRadiologyData] rd 
  where rd.ExaminationDate >= '01 april 2016'
  and   rd.AttendanceSiteCode IN('CNM','RNM')
  ORDER BY rd.LocalPatientIdentifier, rd.ExaminationDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT s.attendanceNumber,s.examinationDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 1 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 2 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 3 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode3,
       ..... As many as you need
FROM (
    SELECT  [AttendanceNumber]
           ,[ExaminationDate]
           ,[ExamExaminationCode]
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [AttendanceNumber] ORDER BY [ExaminationDate]) as rnk --Ordered by date ASC 
      FROM [Radiotherapy].[dbo].[tblRadiologyData] rd 
      where rd.ExaminationDate >= '01 april 2016'
      and   rd.AttendanceSiteCode IN('CNM','RNM') ) s
GROUP BY s.attendanceNumber,s.examinationDate
```

Comment: Wow work great, so now I have my data, is it possible to show the number of combinations and a count (e.g. ExamCode1, ExamCode2 combo occurs x number of times.

Comment: @Simon I'm not sure I understand what you need.. What do you mean by combination ?

Comment: Its Ok solved it, but there is no way to rank the order given the exam date is the same for each attendance number, so each time I run this it's giving me a different output!

Comment: Ok sorted that one now, order by RadiologyID which is incremental per AttendanceNumber, thanks for all your help on this one!

Comment: You should accept Sagi's answer @Simon since it clearly was a good solution